# Compute the distances between points of neighboring time points and find the `n` shortest paths though all time points

Tags: r, algorithm

Exactly as the title states: I'd like to compute the distances between points of neighboring time points and find the `n` shortest paths though all time points.

I've posted an example below. In this example there are 2 clear areas (in 3D space) where points are localized. Within each area, we have multiple time points. I'd like to compute the distances between `T1 --> T2 --> ... --> T8` while enforcing the time point ordering. I ultimately see this as a tree of some sort where we initially branch from the first point of T1 to the 2 (or more) points from T2, then from each T2 to each T3, etc. Once a tree is built then we can compute the distances through each path from start to end and return the top `n` paths with the smallest distances. In short, the goal here is to connect each T1 node with its respective shortest path. Perhaps there might be a more efficient or better way to do this.

Example data:

```
> example
                   Timepoint Centre.int.X Centre.int.Y Centre.int.Z
FOV4.Beads.T1.C2          T1        5.102       28.529        0.789
FOV4.Beads.T1.C2.1        T1       37.904       50.845        0.837
FOV4.Beads.T2.C2          T2       37.905       50.843        1.022
FOV4.Beads.T2.C2.1        T2        5.083       28.491        0.972
FOV4.Beads.T4.C2          T4       37.925       50.851        0.858
FOV4.Beads.T4.C2.1        T4        5.074       28.479        0.785
FOV4.Beads.T5.C2          T5       37.908       50.847        0.977
FOV4.Beads.T5.C2.1        T5        5.102       28.475        0.942
FOV4.Beads.T6.C2          T6        5.114       28.515        0.643
FOV4.Beads.T6.C2.1        T6       37.927       50.869        0.653
FOV4.Beads.T7.C2          T7       37.930       50.875        0.614
FOV4.Beads.T7.C2.1        T7        5.132       28.525        0.579
FOV4.Beads.T8.C2          T8        4.933       28.674        0.800
FOV4.Beads.T8.C2.1        T8       37.918       50.816        0.800
```

This data.frame produces a 3D scatterplot that looks like this: 
[image]

Baseline code to generate the plot above is posted below:

```
require(scatterplot3d)
    with(example, {
      s3d <- scatterplot3d(Centre.int.X, Centre.int.Y, Centre.int.Z,
                           pch=19,
                           cex.symbols=2,
                           col.axis="grey", col.grid="lightblue",
                           angle=45, 
                           xlab="X",
                           ylab="Y",
                           zlab="Z")
    })
```

This is a relatively clean example but some of my data is very messy which is why I am trying to avoid clustering methods (e.g. k-means, dbscan, etc). Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Adding structure details.

```
structure(list(Timepoint = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3", 
"T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8"), class = "factor"), Centre.int.X = c(5.102, 
37.904, 37.905, 5.083, 37.925, 5.074, 37.908, 5.102, 5.114, 37.927, 
37.93, 5.132, 4.933, 37.918), Centre.int.Y = c(28.529, 50.845, 
50.843, 28.491, 50.851, 28.479, 50.847, 28.475, 28.515, 50.869, 
50.875, 28.525, 28.674, 50.816), Centre.int.Z = c(0.789, 0.837, 
1.022, 0.972, 0.858, 0.785, 0.977, 0.942, 0.643, 0.653, 0.614, 
0.579, 0.8, 0.8)), .Names = c("Timepoint", "Centre.int.X", "Centre.int.Y", 
"Centre.int.Z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("FOV4.Beads.T1.C2", 
"FOV4.Beads.T1.C2.1", "FOV4.Beads.T2.C2", "FOV4.Beads.T2.C2.1", 
"FOV4.Beads.T4.C2", "FOV4.Beads.T4.C2.1", "FOV4.Beads.T5.C2", 
"FOV4.Beads.T5.C2.1", "FOV4.Beads.T6.C2", "FOV4.Beads.T6.C2.1", 
"FOV4.Beads.T7.C2", "FOV4.Beads.T7.C2.1", "FOV4.Beads.T8.C2", 
"FOV4.Beads.T8.C2.1"))
```

Comment: Would making a distance matrix help? `distance.matrix <- dist(example[,2:4])`

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely need a distance matrix. This still does not address how to find the `n` shortest paths though. I ultimately want to connect each T1 node with its respective shortest path.

Comment: There's no T3 in your example. Is that so in the data?

Comment: @csgroen -- yes unfortunately this is the case.

Comment: I assume that in the real data not every time instant is guaranteed to have the same number of spatial points, is that right?

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, that's correct. We are not guaranteed to have the same number to instances for each timepoint. For example, T1 may have 2 instances but T2 may have 4 instances. It would be nice to compute every path with its total distance from T1 to T8 while enforcing the time point ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but it works to find the shortest paths.

```
distance.matrix <- as.matrix(dist(example[,2:4], upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE))

t1s <- grep("T1", rownames(distance.matrix))
paths <- lapply(t1s, function (t) { 
    path <- rownames(distance.matrix)[t]
    distance <- NULL
    for (i in c(2,4:8))
    {
        next.nodes <- grep(paste0("T", i), rownames(distance.matrix))
        next.t <- names(which.min(distance.matrix[t,next.nodes]))
        path <- c(path, next.t)
        distance <- sum(distance, distance.matrix[t,next.t])
        t <- next.t

    }
    output <- list(path, distance)
    names(output) <- c("Path", "Total Distance")
    return(output)
})
```

EDIT: Cut off some lines that weren't needed.

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to run it. what is `t` in your `path` definition?

Comment: Also is there a way to associate each path with it's total distance? Also do we need to remove zeros on the diag of the distance matrix?

Comment: t is the next node, which is the min between the next.nodes. I'll improve upon the answer a little

Comment: I don't really remove the 0s on the diag in this solution, that's what diag = TRUE does. My previous example in the comment above did, though. Now it also returns total distance.

Comment: `t` isn't defined anywhere before `path` so I run into the error `Error in rownames(distance.matrix)[t] : invalid subscript type 'closure'`. Here, should `t` be `t1s`

Comment: as a bonus, would it be possible to write out all possible paths and corresponding distances while enforcing the time point ordering?

Comment: Sorry, that line wasn't necessary, it was used just for testing the loop. How is it not enforcing the time point ordering?

Comment: I believe it is enforcing the ordering. I was just wondering if it would now be possible to output all possible paths in a similar manner? Right now we have the shortest paths that start at T1 and end at T8, which is great, but can we compute all the paths from T1 to T8 and filter by distance accordingly? I ask because I'd like to compute a distribution of all the total distances.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation in Python:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read data
s = """Name                      Timepoint Centre.int.X Centre.int.Y Centre.int.Z
FOV4.Beads.T1.C2          T1        5.102       28.529        0.789
FOV4.Beads.T1.C2.1        T1       37.904       50.845        0.837
FOV4.Beads.T2.C2          T2       37.905       50.843        1.022
FOV4.Beads.T2.C2.1        T2        5.083       28.491        0.972
FOV4.Beads.T4.C2          T4       37.925       50.851        0.858
FOV4.Beads.T4.C2.1        T4        5.074       28.479        0.785
FOV4.Beads.T5.C2          T5       37.908       50.847        0.977
FOV4.Beads.T5.C2.1        T5        5.102       28.475        0.942
FOV4.Beads.T6.C2          T6        5.114       28.515        0.643
FOV4.Beads.T6.C2.1        T6       37.927       50.869        0.653
FOV4.Beads.T7.C2          T7       37.930       50.875        0.614
FOV4.Beads.T7.C2.1        T7        5.132       28.525        0.579
FOV4.Beads.T8.C2          T8        4.933       28.674        0.800
FOV4.Beads.T8.C2.1        T8       37.918       50.816        0.800"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(s), sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0, header=0)

# Get time point ids
ts = sorted(df.Timepoint.unique())
# Get the spatial points in each time point
points = [df[df.Timepoint == t].iloc[:, -3:].values.copy() for t in ts]
# Get the spatial point names in each time point
point_names = [list(df[df.Timepoint == t].index) for t in ts]

# Find the best next point starting from the end
best_nexts = []
accum_dists = [np.zeros(len(points[-1]))]
for t_prev, t_next in zip(reversed(points[:-1]), reversed(points[1:])):
    t_dists = np.linalg.norm(t_prev[:, np.newaxis, :] - t_next[np.newaxis, :, :], axis=-1)
    t_dists += accum_dists[-1][np.newaxis, :]
    t_best_nexts = np.argmin(t_dists, axis=1)
    t_accum_dists = t_dists[np.arange(len(t_dists)), t_best_nexts]
    best_nexts.append(t_best_nexts)
    accum_dists.append(t_accum_dists)
# Reverse back the best next points and accumulated distances
best_nexts = list(reversed(best_nexts))
accum_dists = list(reversed(accum_dists))

# Reconstruct the paths
paths = []
for i, p in enumerate(point_names[0]):
    cost = accum_dists[0][i]
    path = [p]
    idx = i
    for t_best_nexts, t_point_names in zip(best_nexts, point_names[1:]):
        next_idx = t_best_nexts[idx]
        path.append(t_point_names[next_idx])
        idx = next_idx
    paths.append((path, cost))

for i, (path, cost) in enumerate(paths):
    print("Path {} (total distance {}):".format(i, cost))
    print("\n".join("\t{}".format(p) for p in path))
    print()
```

Output:

```
Path 0 (total distance 1.23675871386137):
    FOV4.Beads.T1.C2
    FOV4.Beads.T2.C2.1
    FOV4.Beads.T4.C2.1
    FOV4.Beads.T5.C2.1
    FOV4.Beads.T6.C2
    FOV4.Beads.T7.C2.1
    FOV4.Beads.T8.C2

Path 1 (total distance 1.031072818390815):
    FOV4.Beads.T1.C2.1
    FOV4.Beads.T2.C2
    FOV4.Beads.T4.C2
    FOV4.Beads.T5.C2
    FOV4.Beads.T6.C2.1
    FOV4.Beads.T7.C2
    FOV4.Beads.T8.C2.1
```

*Explanation:*

It is basically the same as the [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm). You start at the end, and assign an initial cost to every final node of zero. Then, for every pair of contiguous time points `t_prev` and `t_next` you compute the distance between every possible pair of points and add the previously accumulated costs of the points in `t_next`. Then pick the lowest cost next point for every point in `t_prev` and continue to the previous time point. In the end, `best_nexts` contains, for every point in every time point, the best possible point to go to in the next time point.

The reconstruction is just a matter of following these indices in `best_nexts`. For each possible initial point, pick the best point in the next time point and go on.

Comment: Btw I'm sorry if the other answer is the same algorithm... I'm far from fluent in R and without explanation I cannot tell how that algorithm is working.

Comment: That you for the through write up! I'm currently working in R but this python implementation is portable to R.

Comment: @user2117258 I've made a small change to output the total distance of each path (it's calculated during the execution of the algorithm in `accum_dists`).

Comment: Is it possible to output all possible paths from T1 to T8 with their respective distances? So ultimately the superset of these two paths.

Comment: @user2117258 Hmm not with this algorithm, I mean unless I'm misunderstanding you that sounds more like a full tree exploration, which is probably most easily done (breath-first or depth-first) in a recursive manner.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!